# Differential equation with complex roots and undetermined coefficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Hey guys i need help with this problem:

$y''-4y'+5y=6e^{2x}sinx$

I get the roots from the characteristic equation.
$r^2-4r+5=0$
$\implies r=2\pm i $

Then i set up:

$y_{h}=c_{1}e^{2x}sinx+c_{2}e^{2x}cosx$

And i know that:

$y_p=e^{2x}(Asinx+Bcosx)x $

But the problem arrives when i differentiate. The problem is the x on the end i dont know how to work with it, i can solve the other differential equation types.  For this problem i end up with:

$$-xBcosx-2Bcosx+4Acosx-2xBsinx-xAsinx+2Bsinx$$

After differentiating and putting it back into the equation. But i dont know what to do with the x's.

Comment: Try it without adding the $x$.

Comment: Tried that, got the wrong answer, maybe i do it wrong.
$$e^{2x}(Asinx+Bcosx)  

y_{p}=(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}    

y_{p}'=(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}+2(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}  

y_{p}''=2(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}+(-Asinx-    Bcosx)e^{2x}+4(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}+2(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}  

2(Acosx-Bsinx)+(-Asinx-Bcosx)+4(Asinx+Bcosx)+2(Acosx-Bsinx)  

-4Acosx+4Bsinx-8Asinx-8Bcosx+5Asinx+5Bcosx=6sinx+0cosx  

\newline (-2B-A+4A-2B+4B-8A+5A)sinx+(2A-B+4B+2A-4A-8B+5B)cosx$$  It equals to 0. The answer is supposed to be $-3xe^{2x}cosx.  Can't get comment to newline :(

Comment: Your $y_p(x)$ is correct. When you sub it back into the DEQ, you end up with $2 e^{2 x}( A \cos x - b \sin x) = 6 e^{2 x} \sin x$, which is easy.

Comment: $e^{2x}(Asinx+Bcosx)$


$y_{p}=(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}$


$y_{p}'=(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}+2(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}$


$y_{p}''=2(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}+(-Asinx-Bcosx)e^{2x}+4(Asinx+Bcosx)e^{2x}+2(Acosx-Bsinx)e^{2x}$  

$2(Acosx-Bsinx)+(-Asinx-Bcosx)+4(Asinx+Bcosx)+2(Acosx-Bsinx)$  


$-4Acosx+4Bsinx-8Asinx-8Bcosx+5Asinx+5Bcosx=6sinx+0cosx$  


$(-2B-A+4A-2B+4B-8A+5A)sinx+(2A-B+4B+2A-4A-8B+5B)cosx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If I may suggest.*

You can make your life much easier if you start from the very beginning using $$y=e^{2x}z \implies y'=e^{2 x} \left(z'+2 z\right)\implies y''=e^{2 x} \left(z''+4 z'+4z\right)$$ This makes the differential equation to be $$z''+z=6\sin(x)$$ and then, almost as you wrote, the particular solution will be $$z_p=x(A \sin(x)+B \cos(x))$$ $$z'_p=\sin (x) (A-B x)+\cos (x) (A x+B)$$ $$z''_p=\cos (x) (2 A-B x)-\sin (x) (A x+2 B)$$ $$z_p''+z_p=2 A \cos (x)-2 B \sin (x)=6\sin(x)$$ which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The first derivative of $y_p$ should be $$Be^{2x}\cos x + 2B e^{2x}x\cos x - Be^{2x}x \sin x + A e^{2x}x\cos x + Ae^{2x} \sin x + 2Ae^{2x}x \sin x $$
and the second derivative should be
$$-Be^{2x}x \cos x + 4Be^{2x}\cos x +4Be^{2x}x\cos x - 2Be^{2x} \sin x - 4Be^{2x}x \sin x + 2Ae^{2x}\cos x + 4Ae^{2x}x \cos x - Ae^{2x}x\sin x + 4Ae^{2x}\sin x +4Ae^{2x}x \sin x,$$

and plugging back into the original equation, everything cancels out nicely so that you can solve for $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you, after some sleep i cut all the ()'s and did it all over again and got the correct answer! My main problem was with f(x)g(x)h(x) being to cumbersome to differentiate properly when they were to complicated.